# inserting " " key into map

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, stl

While inserting key, value pair into a map, What will be the behavior if the key is " " and corresponding that value is present. for example

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> map1;
std::string key = "";
std::string value = "xyz";

map1.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(key, value));
```

And what is the best way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Are you asking if `map::insert` has special behavior for empty strings?

Comment: juanchopanza is there any special behavior? Is such scenario valid? how can I avoid this particular scenario?

Comment: No, there isn't any special behaviour, but your question implies that it is, or that you haven't read any documentation for `map::insert`.

Comment: Or that you think that `std::string` has a special state, "null". That isn't true either. All you have is an empty string. Could that be the source of confusion?

Comment: Ahhh .. Thanks a lot. corrected myself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::string` does not have a special state or value "null". A string initialized with `""` is just an empty string, but it is still a string like any other. When using it as a key, [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) will do what it always does: insert the element only if no element with the same key already exists.

Note that you can check whether the insert succeeded using the second member of the return value:

```
auto res = map1.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(key, value));
std::cout << std::boolalpha;
std::cout << "Success? " << res.second << '\n'; // Success? true

// try again (and fail)
auto res = map1.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(key, value));
std::cout << "Success? " << res.second << '\n'; // Success? false
```